# How to select multiple cells in QTableView (PyQt4)?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I have created a table in PyQt4 using QTableView. I have used "ExtendedSelection" as a Selection Mode to select the multiple cells in the TableView but I am not able to select the multiple cells. I have also tried "MultiSelection" but still not getting it?

*** Same command (QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection) works well in QTableWidget.

```
def __init__(self, table, parent=None):

    super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setObjectName("CPT")
    self.resize(965, 210)
    self.setWindowTitle("CPT")
    self.model = CablesModel(self)
    self.model.setTable(table)
    self.model.setRelation(Col10, QSqlRelation("STATE", "id", "state"))
    self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    self.model.select()

    self.view = QTableView(self) 
    self.view.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 948, 166))
    self.view.setModel(self.model)
    self.view.setSelectionMode(QTableView.ExtendedSelection)
    self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.CurrentChanged)
    self.view.setFocusPolicy(Qt.ClickFocus)
    self.view.setColumnHidden(Col1, True)
    self.view.setColumnWidth(Col10, 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution... What I did is that just removed one line from the code.

## self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.CurrentChanged)

And everything worked fine. Now I am able to select the bunch of cells in QTableView.

Thanks!!!